# Cannot read property 'readyState' of undefined

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

spend hours to find what has gone wrong, but failed.. since I'm new to Ajax, so I've no idea what I'm seeing. really need you guys to find the bug.

HTML

```
    <!doctype html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="foodstore.js"></script>
</head>

<body onload="process()">
    <h3>The Chuff Bucket</h3>
    Enter the food you would like to order:
    <input type="text" id="userInput">
    <div id="underInput" />
</body>

</html>
```

javascript :

```
var xmlHttp = createXmlHttpRequestObject();

function createXmlHttpRequestObject(){
    var xmlHttp;

    if(window.ActiveXobject){
        try{
            xmlHttp = new ActiveXobject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");

        }catch(e){
            xmlHttp = false;
        }
    }else{
        try{
            xmlHttp = new XmlHttpRequest();
        }catch(e){
            xmlHttp = false;
        }
    }

    if(!xmlHttp){
        alert("can't create that object");
    }
    else{
        return xmlHttp;
    }
}

function process(){
    if(xmlHttp.readyState==0 || xmlHttp.readyState==4){
        food = encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("userInput").value);
        xmlHttp.open("GET", "foodstore.php?food=" + food, true);
        xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = handleServerResponse;
        xmlHttp.send(null);
    }else{
        setTimeout('process()', 1000);
    }

}

function handleServerResponse(){
    if(xmlHttp.readyState==4){
        if(xmlHttp.status==200){
            xmlResponse = xmlHttp.responseXML;
            xmlDocumentElement = xmlResponse.documentElement;
            message = xmlDocumentElement.firstChild.data;
            document.getElementById("underInput").innerHTML = "<span style='color:blue'>" + message + "</span>";
                    setTimeout('process()', 1000);

        }else{
            alert('something went wrong');
        }
    }
}
```

PHP (I think this file caused the problem)

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/xml');
echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?>';

echo '<response>';
    $food = $_GET['food'];
    $foodArray = array('tuna','bacon','beef','ham');

    if(in_array($food,$foodArray)){
        echo 'We do have ' .$food. '!';
    }else if($food == ''){
        echo 'Enter a food name.';
    }else 
    {
        echo "no, we don't sell " .$food. "!";
    }

echo '</response>';

?>
```

Comment: Not a solution, but you should *never* pass strings to `setTimeout`.  That makes it use `eval`, which is bad!  Pass a function: `setTimeout(process, 1000);`

Comment: I agree with Rocket Hazmat about the string parameter for setTimeout, but besides this I don't see an issue with your code. So probably the error is somewhere else ...

Comment: What does your PHP code actually echo out?  Are you sure it's valid XML?

Comment: On what line / at what point are you getting the 'undefined' error?

Comment: I'm amazed this code does not produce more errors. why are you calling `open` and `send` over and over again on the same _XHR_?

Comment: @PaulS.: While not great practice, I don't think that's an error.  Also, his URL is dynamically changing, so how else do you send an AJAX to a "new" URL?

Comment: Another point: why use `setTimeout` for this need when it would be better to use events?

Comment: @PaulRoub it is most likely line `1` of `process` by looking at invocation order

Comment: Did any of your `alerts` fire?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript is case sensitive. You've got some syntax errors due to improper casing on some of the objects you're trying to create:

```
ActiveXobject
```

should be

```
ActiveXObject
       ^
```

and

```
XmlHttpRequest
```

should be

```
XMLHttpRequest
 ^^
```

The end result is that you're trying to create things that don't exist, resulting in the `xmlHttp` variable that is always `false` or `undefined`.

Comment: Also `new XmlHttpRequest`.  The `m` and `l` should be uppercase.

Comment: @GeorasViverosAguilera: Can you be more specific? *What's* not working? Have you tried debugging with any browser development tools? Do you get any errors?

Answer (score 2):

Your object creation logic seems backward (should try to create the modern object when you can, do the IE thing only if necessary), and mis-capitalized.

Try:

```
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        try {
            xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } catch(e) {
            xmlHttp = false;
        }
    } else {
        try{
            xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");

        }catch(e){
            xmlHttp = false;
        }
    }
```